# Set a property on window with cypress

Tags: reactjs, authentication, window, android-webview, cypress

I need to test a react app that is supposed to run as a webview within another native app. The webview server sets session variables into the window, which is further used to authenticate my app.

I want to mock this by doing something like:

```
window.appEnvironment={ 
//session variables
}
```

I have tried cy.window() , but it doesnt seem to help.
How can I set properties on window from cypress.

Answer (score 15):

Put this into the support file:

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
    win.appEnvironment = { 
        //session variables
    }
});
```

Now this snippet will be evaluated before any of your application code is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

miklos_me almost had it right. You should use the passed in win object instead of the global window object.

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
    win.appEnvironment = { 
        //session variables
    }
});
```

Comment: This probably could've been a comment under the other answer